# Trouble with templates and for loops

Tags: c++, templates, for-loop

I have this code, which is giving me a single error that indicates two problems.

```
int healthyConst = 0;
int sickConst = 1;
int recoveredConst = 2;

GraphMatrix<int, double> graph (100);
for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
{
    if(std::rand() % 2 > 0.05) graph.setVertexInfo(i, sickConst); //Error
    else graph.setVertexInfo(i, healthyConst); 
}
```

The error is:

> error: no matching function for call to GraphMatrix::setVertexInfo(int&, int*)

And the function in question is declared as follows in the source:

> void GraphMatrix::setVertexInfo(int v, VertexObject& info)

First, i should not be a reference. This seems nonsensical to me, yet I can not fix this. If I try to outsmart the compiler and type `for(int* i = 0...)` the error now complains of `setVertexInfo(int&*, int*)`, and I don't even understand what this means.

Second, sickConst is not a pointer. It is just an int. Now I realize the method, as written, accepts VertexObject&, not VertexObject, but `*sickConst` also causes the compiler to complain of `invalid type argument of 'unary *'`. I've also tried `&sickConst`, which the compiler not unexpectedly interprets as a pointer.

Also note, identical errors are thrown for the second line of the for loop, presumably for the same reasons.

The question is: why am I getting these errors, and how do I fix them?

Answer (score 2):

You stated that your function declaration within the source is as follows:

> void GraphMatrix::setVertexInfo(int v, VertexObject& info)

However in your for loop you are passing it a type of `int`. Either change your function declaration & definition to accept a type of `int` or change the type that you are passing to your function as a `VertexObject`.